# js, how to get one part in location.hash

Tags: javascript

I want to get the `location.hash` part, the word after first `%20`. But how?

For explain

```
http://localhost/text/search.php?search=sweet%20girl  => girl
http://localhost/text/search.php?search=fashion  => NULL
http://localhost/text/search.php?search=2011%20best%20and%20worst => best and worst
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var s = decodeURIComponent(location.search);
var index = s.indexOf(" ");
s = index === -1 ? s.substr(index + 1) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) function first. After that you can do a regexp [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

```
var url = "http://localhost/text/search.php?search=2011%20best%20and%20worst";
alert (unescape(url).replace(/^\S* /,""));
```